# Add gutter on masonry with the bootstrap3 grid

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, masonry

I'm having trouble with coding gutter on masonry with the bootstrap3 grid.

This is my jsfiddle.   https://jsfiddle.net/shelly_W/bg67fdjm/

```
<div class="container bg">
<h1>Masonry - Bootstrap 3 grid media queries</h1>
<!-- add extra container element for Masonry -->
<div class="grid">
<div class="grid-sizer col-xs-6 col-sm-4"></div>
<div class="grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 ">
<!-- add inner element for column content -->
<div class="grid-item-content grid-item-content--height400">1</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
<div class="grid-item-content grid-item-content--height230">2</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
<div class="grid-item-content grid-item-content--height443">3</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
<div class="grid-item-content grid-item-content--height230">4</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
<div class="grid-item-content grid-item-content--height518">5</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
<div class="grid-item-content grid-item-content--height518">6</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
<div class="grid-item-content grid-item-content--height230">7</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
<div class="grid-item-content grid-item-content--height230">8</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Source is: https://masonry.desandro.com/

What I’m trying to achieve is having 15px gutters between the masonry grid. I want to create a space between grid 1 and grid 2. I don’t want padding on either of the outer container div edges of grid 1 or grid 2.
I attempted to insert a 15px gutter by js, but this approach breaks the bootstrap responsive columns.

I’ve been trying to work this out for some time, but I can't figure out the right approach. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might resolve this issue?

Please let me know if you need any further information.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove your current `padding` declarations on your `.grid-size` selector and use `margin-bottom` instead.

```
.grid-size {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
}
```

You can use a static value if you'd prefer; I used it a percentage here because you're going for a responsive design.

Here you can see your [fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/bg67fdjm/10/) and in action.

Comment: This approach has 30px gutters between the items (the OP requested 15px).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution that goes all the way to the edges and maintains a 15px gutter, you can keep your padding and use the CSS `calc()` method to adjust for the responsive container.

```
.grid-sizer { width:calc(33.33% - 10px); }
.grid-item { width: calc(33.33% - 10px); }
.grid-item--width2 { width: calc(66.66% - 5px); }
```

Then you just need to add media queries to your CSS to responsively change the width of the items:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .grid-sizer { width:calc(50% - 7.5px); }
  .grid-item { width: calc(50% - 7.5px); }
  .grid-item--width2 { width: 100%; }
}
@media (max-width: 350px) {
  .grid-sizer { width:100%; }
  .grid-item { width: 100%; }
}
```

Check out this fiddle:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bg67fdjm/12/)

Comment: This approach greatly distorts the perspective of the grid items' content. Minimize the output quadrant to see what I mean.

Comment: Just updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bg67fdjm/12/) with media queries to account for smaller window size.

Comment: @shelly-w - Does [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/bg67fdjm/12/) work for your grid?